# Using 'select' tag with entities in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am creating a form with the select tag that looks like this:

```
<form th:object="${version}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    ...
    <div class="control-group" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('product')} ? 'error'">
        <label class="control-label" for="product" th:text="#{version.product}">Product</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select id="product" th:field="*{product}">
                <option value="" th:text="#{common.select.prompt}"></option>
                <option th:each="p : ${productList}" th:value="${p.id}"  th:text="${p.name}"></option>
            </select>
            <span class="help-inline" th:errors="*{product}"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

`DomainClassConverter` class of `Spring Data JPA` helps to auto-convert selected `id` to the entity `Product` when I submit the form. The `product` should also be not null (I am using `@NotNull` on the `product` field in the `Version` class.

The problem that I have - when I come back to edit the data, the `Product` is not selected.

If I modify the `select` like this (`th:field` and `th:errors`): `<-- p.s. is not a sad smile`

```
<select id="product" th:field="*{product.id}">
    <option value="" th:text="#{common.select.prompt}"></option>
    <option th:each="p : ${productList}" th:value="${p.id}" th:text="${p.name}"></option>
</select>
<span class="help-inline" th:errors="*{product.id}"></span>
```

then it becomes selected when I come back to edit it, but the validator doesn't work (`product` is always instantiated, even if selected id is `null`).

It looks like a very common scenario (selecting an entity from the list), but I cannot find any good looking example. Please share the secret knowledge.

Comment: What do you mean by come back to edit it?

Comment: I use the same page for create and edit of the Version entity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. The problem existed because I had not overridden the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods.

Comment: This had be banging my head on my desk for a while, glad you figured it out.

Comment: 5 years ago that is